# Ruby hash group by value

Tags: ruby

I have a ruby hash containing student name and mark as follows.

```
student_marks = {
    "Alex" => 50,
    "Beth" => 54,
    "Matt" => 50
}
```

I am looking for a solution to group students according to their mark.

```
{
    50 => ["Alex", "Matt"],
    54 => ["Beth"]
}
```

I have tried `group_by` but it didn't give me the desired result. Following is the result of using `group_by`.

```
student_marks.group_by {|k,v| v}
{50=>[["Alex", 50], ["Matt", 50]], 54=>[["Beth", 54]]}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
student_marks.group_by { |k, v| v }.map { |k, v| [k, v.map(&:first)] }.to_h
#=> { 50 => ["Alex", "Matt"], 54 => ["Beth"]}
```

Comment: This is so helpful. Thank you :)

Answer (score 6):

```
student_marks.group_by(&:last).transform_values { |v| v.map(&:first) }
  #=> {50=>["Alex", "Matt"], 54=>["Beth"]}
```

[Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html) made its debut in Ruby MRI v2.4.0.

Comment: This is reporting this error `: undefined method transform_values' for {50=>[["Alex", 50], ["Matt", 50]], 54=>[["Beth", 54]]}:Hash (NoMethodError)`

Comment: @Rajagopalan, I just did an edit that I expect explains why you got the no-method error. Whenever code works for one person (as it clearly did for me) but not for another (you), it is invariably a version issue. I used v2.5.1

Answer (score 4):

Another way could be

```
student_marks.each.with_object(Hash.new([])){ |(k,v), h| h[v] += [k] }
#=> {50=>["Alex", "Matt"], 54=>["Beth"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another easy way

```
student_marks.keys.group_by{ |v| student_marks[v] }
{50=>["Alex", "Matt"], 54=>["Beth"]}
```

Comment: Indeed this is a much easier way.